# How to trigger onListItemClick in a ListFragment

Tags: android, listview, android-fragments

In the tablet layout of my app, I have three ListFragments and one regular Fragment, let's call them Make, Model, Size, and Details.  Initially the Make list is populated, then based on the Make selection, the Model list is populated; when a Model is selected, the Size list is populated; when a Size is selected, Details are shown.  Each of these events (list item selection) is handled through the onListItemClick handler.

On startup, I want to populate the Make list, select the first Make in the list and have it go through the onListItemClick handler to populate the Model list (and so on so that all lists are populated and the details are shown - this should also be the behavior when any selection is made in any of the lists - select the first item in the next list until we get to showing the details).  Note that I have control of the DB and for every Make there will always be at least one Model, for each Make/Model at least one Size, for each Make/Model/Size exactly one Detail.

So, I want to select the first item in the list and have it trigger the onListItemClick handler.  I've tried the following (with appropriate bounds checking, etc), but it doesn't work.

```
getListView().setItemChecked(0, true);
```

The only changes to an "out of the box" ListFragment are to set the CacheColorHint as such

```
getListView().setCacheColorHint(R.color.GhostWhite);
```

where GhostWhite is set in the styles.xml as

```
<color name="GhostWhite">#88FFFFFF</color>
```

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

To select the first item in the list, first get focus from touch, then select the first item, then trigger the onclick handler

```
int position = 0;
getListView().requestFocusFromTouch();
getListView().setSelection(position);
getListView().performItemClick(getListView().getAdapter().getView(position, null, null), position, position);
```

Comment: The only missing piece to the puzzle is where to place this code. It works perfectly in the onActivityCreated. Be sure to execute the super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState); or no joy. I tried it in onViewCreated and I didn't get the list, just the right side view.

Answer (score 1):

Try setSelection(int position)

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ListView.html#setSelection(int)

Comment: it certainly looks like it should work, but it is not working for me.

Answer (score 1):

1.) In the OnActivityCreated of your list fragment create an interface like so

```
public interface ListItemSelectedListener {
        public void onListItemSelected(int index);
}
```

2.) Implement the interface in your activity 
3.) Create `private ListItemSelectedListener selectedListener` in your list fragment
4.) Set `selectedListener.onListItemSelected(0)` in the OnActivityCreated.

This is how it worked for me using the Android Support Package - should be similar on HC

Answer (score 1):

Try adding this,, it works in my project:

```
@Override
public void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);
    Intent intent = new Intent();
    intent.setClass(getActivity(), someActivity.class);
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

Comment: can someone please point me when i am trying to apply clickListener on ListView and trying to scroll the listview on scrolling my app crashed here is my question i have asked in SO but did not get any solution     http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21091429/failed-to-print-position-of-clickeditem-of-listview-in-android-using-java/21091513?noredirect=1#comment31725907_21091513

Answer (score 1):

in The Fragment class in **onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState)** method, you can add the following:

```
@Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
        //if the parent is in the landscape, make the first item selected
        if (getActivity().getResources().getConfiguration().orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE) {
            try {
                if (mItems.size() > 0) {
                    //notify the activity that an item is selected
                    mListener.onMasterItemSelected(mItems.get(0));
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.e("exception", e.toString());
            }
        }
    }
```