# notifyDataSetChanged in Curser adapter not working with listfragment

Tags: android, android-listfragment

I have a listfragment that displays a list from a database. I have everthing working correctly except for a small item that I can't seeem to clear up. The list view looks something like this.

```
-----------------------------------------------------
text text text | some more text | delete row button |
-----------------------------------------------------
```

My problem: when a user presses the delete row button the row is deleted from the database but will not be removed from the screen until the activity is stopped and started again.

I know that `notifyDataSetChanged()` is the preferred method for updating these lists but it does not seem to do anything... Anyhow, below is my code for the cursor adapter where `notifyDataSetChanged()` is called.

```
public class CalcCursorAdapter extends SimpleCursorAdapter{

    private Context mContext;
    private ListView mListView;
    private int mLayout;
    private Cursor mcursor;

    protected static class ViewHolder {
        protected TextView text;
        protected ImageButton button;
        private int position;
      }


    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    public CalcCursorAdapter(Context context, int layout, Cursor c, String[] from, int[] to) 
    {
        super(context, layout, c, from, to);
        this.mContext = context;
        this.mLayout = layout;
        this.mcursor = c;

        //mListView = .getListView();

    }       

    @Override
    public void bindView(View view, Context context, Cursor cursor) {
        TextView summary = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.calctvPrice);
        TextView savings = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.calctvSavings);
        TextView percentOff = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.calctvpercentOff);
        summary.setText(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow("qcFinalPrice")));




    }

    @Override
    public View newView(Context context, Cursor cursor, ViewGroup parent) {
        ViewHolder holder = new ViewHolder();

        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.calc_list_item, parent, false);

        holder.button = (ImageButton) v.findViewById(R.id.qcbtnDelete);
        holder.button.setOnClickListener(deleteButton);
        holder.position = cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow("_id"));
        bindView(v, context, cursor);
        v.setTag(holder);


        return v;

    }

    private OnClickListener deleteButton = new OnClickListener() {
        @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
        public void onClick(View v){
            View view = (View) v.getParent();
            ViewHolder holder = (ViewHolder) view.getTag();
            int position = holder.position;
            DbHelper mDbHelper;
            mDbHelper = new DbHelper(mContext);
            mDbHelper.open();
            mDbHelper.deleteCalc(position);
            mDbHelper.close();
            String test = Integer.toString(position);
            Toast.makeText(mContext.getApplicationContext(), test, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();  
            notifyDataSetChanged();



            //ListView list = getListView();


        }
    };

    public long qcItemId(int position) {

        return position;
    }




}
```

Thank you for your help.

UPDATE:

New button Code within my adapter:

```
private OnClickListener deleteButton = new OnClickListener() {
    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    public void onClick(View v){
        v.invalidate();
        View view = (View) v.getParent();
        view.invalidate();
        ViewHolder holder = (ViewHolder) view.getTag();
        int position = holder.position;
        DbHelper mDbHelper;
        mDbHelper = new DbHelper(mContext);
        mDbHelper.open();
        mDbHelper.deleteCalc(position);
        mDbHelper.close();
        String test = Integer.toString(position);
        Toast.makeText(mContext.getApplicationContext(), test, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();  
        Cursor newCursor = getCursor();
        changeCursor(newCursor);
        notifyDataSetChanged();



        //ListView list = getListView();


    }
};
```

Comment: how did you solved issue

Comment: Hey Marek did you solve the issue if yes please let us know the answer .

Answer (score 8):

I got the same problem before, I don't think in this case `notifyDataSetChanged` alone can help you. What has changed is actually your cursor, so you need to reload it using the function [changeCursor](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/CursorAdapter.html#changeCursor%28android.database.Cursor%29) on your custom adapter. Here is an example:

```
changeCursor(yourCursor);
notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Here is the full code of how I managed this in my Fragment class:

```
ImageButton newCat = (ImageButton)categoriesListTitle.findViewById(R.id.new_category);

            newCat.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(final View v) {
                    categoriesDialog.dismiss();

                    AlertDialog.Builder newCatAlert = new AlertDialog.Builder(new ContextThemeWrapper(getActivity(), R.style.AlertDialogStyle));

                    newCatAlert.setTitle("New category");

                    // Set an EditText view to get user input 
                    final EditText newCatET = new EditText(v.getContext());
                    newCatAlert.setView(newCatET);

                    newCatAlert.setPositiveButton("Ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
                            String newCatName = newCatET.getText().toString();

                            db.addCategory(newCatName);
                            mAdapter.changeCursor(db.getAllCategoriesByRate(currentRate));//Here I update the cursor used in my adapter
                            //In your case (you do not use a dialog), you have to add this line I think:
                            //mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

                            categoriesDialog.show();
                        }

                    });

                    newCatAlert.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
                            dialog.cancel();
                        }
                    });
                    newCatAlert.show();
                }
            });


            categoriesLV.setAdapter(mAdapter);
```

Comment: I added
`Curser newCursor = getCursor();
changeCursor(newCursor);`
after my database delete and this does nothing... it does not throw errors, it just does not do anything! Thanks for the help!

Comment: I edited my answer, in my case I did not need to use `notifyDataSetChanged` because I was using a popup to display again the list, but for you it might be useful. Have it a try.

Comment: I have edited my main post to display better the code for my button within my adapter with these changes... I would like to verify that you know I'm working with a list fragment... not sure if that matters or not as this happens in the adapter and not the fragment.

Comment: What does return your `getCursor` function? It should call again your DB to get an updated cursor.

Comment: I find this hard because I uses a loadermanager inside the fragment. And as hard as I have tried I have not been able to instigate the loader inside of the of the adapter... And because it is inside a fragment and the adapter is outside the fragment I have not been able to tell it to re-query... I'm sorry I'm not so good at this.

Comment: You should I think call the `changeCursor` function in the Fragment, not in the Adapter. I updated my answer to show you a full event I manage in my own fragment to dynamically add a new category in a categories list.

Comment: I see what you did and I CAN update it from the fragment. The problem is because this button (delete button) is in every row I handle the click event inside the adapter (that way I can figure out what row was clicked). I would not mind passing this all to the fragment and letting it handle it but I'm not able to pass any infromation into a fragment from the adapter, that I know of... In the list fragment I have a public refreshlist function... but I can not call the fragment manager from a non-fragment. thank you for all your help and sorry if I'm missing something simple and stupid!

Comment: OK so actually the problem is not the `notifyDataSetChanged` here, you have to move back your listener on your ListFragment class. Check these 3 links, maybe they explain why you got a problem the first time you tried: 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7274231/listfragment-onlistitemclick-not-being-called
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9690439/creating-custom-simple-cursor-adapter
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8611612/how-to-trigger-onlistitemclick-in-a-listfragment